# sas studio remote login

Tags: sas, remote-server

Hi I am trying to login to a remote server(UNIX) from SAS studio and this is what I wrote.

```
signon sasserver;
```

this gives an error

```
ERROR: A communication subsystem partner link setup request failure has     
occurred. ERROR: No terminal connected to the SAS session. ERROR: Remote 
signon to SASTST01 canceled.
```

The tcpunix is at the location intact. 
However I am able to login from the SAS base.

Is there any setting that I am suppose to change here on SAS Studio?

Comment: What is SAS Studio pointing to?  Local install (the same as "SAS Base" above)?  A server?  A disk image?

Comment: I would wonder then if the SAS Studio is starting SAS in a slightly different way than your base SAS install - like with a different config for example.  If it were me I'd post this on communities.sas.com - they have a subforum specifically for SAS Studio if I recall correctly.

Comment: Thank you @Joe will do that

Answer (score 1):

I believe SAS Studio authenticates the user via the mid-tier rather than the workspace/metadata server. 
Check the following:

1. If you can login from your office; then its external IP configuration on the webserver.
2. If you can't login from your office, then you need your SAS admin to setup your user account correctly on the sas servers.